# Inside java stream the map function does not recognize my local variable

Tags: java-8, java-stream, jsonnode

I am trying to search inside the flow of a jsonNode using the java stream. At one point I receive an ArrayNode and I have converted it to a List of JsonNodes using a simple private methode in my class; however, when I want to use the map fucntion to map my node I have realized that the local variable (node; inside the first map) is null. I do not understand why and how to solve this problem, considering that I am new in Java 8. I am posting my code here:

```
List<JsonNode> msgs = arrayNodeToListNode((ArrayNode) kmsResponse.at(kmsResponsePath));
        msgs.stream().forEach(t -> {
            List<JsonNode> jsonNodes = arrayNodeToListNode((ArrayNode) t.get("coverageList"));
            List<JsonNode> collect = jsonNodes.stream()
                    .map(node -> node.get("/coverage/coverageTypeLevel"))
                    .filter(node -> formule.equals(node.get("aggReference").textValue()))
                    .map(node -> t.get("premiumSplittedList"))
                    .map(node -> node.get("value")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            String value = collect.toString();
            response.append(collect);
        });
```

Comment: Care to provide some details? You get a compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

If your `node` is `null`, this has nothing to do with streams or Java 8, it's just that your `arrayNodeToListNode` operation is returning some `null` json nodes in the list.

The error (if any) is in the `arrayNodeToListNode` method. If it's valid for that method to return a list with some `null` elements, you can perfectly filter `null`s out before using `Stream.map`, by using `Stream.filter(Objects::nonNull)`:

```
List<JsonNode> jsonNodes = arrayNodeToListNode((ArrayNode) t.get("coverageList"));
List<JsonNode> collect = jsonNodes.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(node -> node.get("/coverage/coverageTypeLevel"))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact I have solved my problem; I was debugging my application in intelliJ and I faced with the fact that in IntelliJ's debugger the node was null. The reason was simply because I did not know in order to add the break points in the debugger mode I needed to chose the `\lambda` instead of "line".

That was the problem. In fact All was good, no null pointer problem. I had in fact another porblem with a filter and as soon as I discovered how the intelliJ's debugger functions for lambda-expressions, I solved my problem. At the end I have this code that functions very well:

```
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    List<JsonNode> msgs = arrayNodeToListNode((ArrayNode) kmsResponse.at(kmsResponsePath));
    List<JsonNode> collect1 = msgs.stream().filter(node -> {
                List<JsonNode> collect = arrayNodeToListNode((ArrayNode) node.get("coverageList")).stream()
                        .map(entry -> entry.at("/coverage/coverageTypeLevel"))
                        .filter(enttry -> formule.equals(enttry.get("aggReference").textValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
                return collect.size() > 0;
            }

    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
response.append(collect1);
```

Thanks However.